# Scala - How to Convert Generic List To Array and avoid "No ClassTag available for T"

Tags: java, scala, types, jvm, classtag

I am working on what should be a trivial piece of code. I want to take a List, and convert it to an equivalent Array:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters

object Help extends App {
  def f1[T](lst: List[T]) = {
    lst.toArray
  }

  val x = List(1, 2, 3)
  println(f1(x))
}
```

Running this code gives:

```
"No ClassTag available for T"
```

How can I avoid this problem; I am coming from a Python background so would appreciate a response that gives me an understanding of the mechanics here.

Thank you!

Comment: This: `import scala.collection.JavaConverters` is unnecessary. Anyways, it is a trivial and common problem, you just need to make this `def f1[T : ClassTag](lst: List[T]): Array[T] = 
{` - BTW, why do you want an **Array**? Arrays are low level primitive, not collections, they have many problems like this one, I would suggest staying away from them, unless you need to use them.

Comment: Thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, I am actually using the gson library and it seems to play better with Arrays then it does with Scala Lists.

Comment: Do not use **gson**, there are at least 5 great Scala son libraries. Why rallying in using a Java one which doesn't play nice with scala types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding implicit `ClassTag` parameter like so

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def f1[T](lst: List[T])(implicit ev: ClassTag[T]) = {
  lst.toArray
}
```

The reason is clear if we have a look at signature of `toArray`

```
def toArray[B >: A: ClassTag]: Array[B]
```

which is equivalent to

```
def toArray[B >: A](implicit ev: ClassTag[B]): Array[B]
```

so you have to thread the implicit parameter from `f1` down to `toArray`.

> would appreciate a response that gives me an understanding of the
>   mechanics here

The key is to understand `Array` is **not** a true Scala collection. For once, it is not a subtype of `Iterable`

```
implicitly[Array[Int] <:< Iterable[Int]] // error
```

Another difference between `Array` and true Scala collections is the absence of need for `ClassTag` for true Scala collections. The reason for this is Scala collections go through a process of type erasure which means runtime knows it is a `List` but does not differentiate between `List[Int]` and `List[String]`, for example. However this does not hold for `Array`. At runtime there is indeed a difference between `Array[Int]` and `Array[String]`. Hence `ClassTag` is a mechanism invented to carry type information, which exists only at compile-time, over to runtime, so `Array` can have the behaviour as in Java.

You will encounter other differences, for example

```
Array(42) == Array(42)  // false
List(42) == List(42)    // true
```

Best practice is to avoid `Array` if possible.

Comment: @finite_diffidence no, why would it? Since arrays are primitives of the JVM they actually are not generic, but rather there are different types of arrays. The class tag is a value that is created in compile time so in runtime it knows which is the actual class so it creates the corresponding array.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, thanks that is insightful indeed.